# How do I ensure that every one of my icons are clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a backend script that generates clickable menu icons for the `User Interface` (UI) similar to the ones illustrated below. Keep in mind that each of these icons hold data qualities that vary from one another:

[image: The menu icon before its clicked]

[image: The menu icon after its been clicked]

The issue I have is that my `click event` only seems to only be tied to the first icon and doesn't work when I click on the second icon.

How can I enable every icon to be clickable?

Find below my `HTML` code with its embedded `JavaScript` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.toolbar.js"></script>
      <link href="css/jquery.toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.gear').toolbar({
                content: '#toolbar-options',
                position: 'right',
                style: 'primary',
                animation: 'standard',
                event: 'click',
                hideOnClick: true
            });
        }); 
      </script>
      
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <h1>Testing toolbar.js</h1>
</header>

    <div class="btn-toolbar btn-toolbar-warning gear" >
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-toolbar btn-toolbar-warning gear" >
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
        
    <div id="toolbar-options" class="hidden btn-toolbar btn-toolbar-primary">
       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"></i></a>
       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i></a>
    </div>          

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can not use the same ID for 2 elements. Use a class. Instead of `#gear` use `.gear` and edit your HTML accordingly

Comment: @AndreaOlivato thank you Andrea! I followed your suggestion and edited my HTML accordingly.